# getting Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program when creating a HttpConfiguration

Tags: c#

I'm running a unit test that creates an `ApiController`.

```
var key = HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey;
var config = new HttpConfiguration(); //this is where the InvalidOperationException gets thrown
controller.Request.Properties.Add(key, config);
...
```

I'm getting the error message below:

```
Test method <test library name>.GetLastObject threw exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
```

I've tried

1. turning off code optimization
2. updating the System.Web.Http library and other libraries using the package manager.

Neither worked. Any ideas?

Also, why is this happening? The error message isn't very clear in describing the problem.

Comment: Are you unwittingly using assemblies meant for .NET Core in your .NET Fx 4.x project, perhaps?

Comment: I would first try to reproduce this in an absolutely minimal way - ideally as a console app. Edit your question to include that, along with your .NET version, OS version etc.

Comment: Alsoi, please clarify exactly what you mean by "the System.Web.Http library"... the types in the `System.Web.Http` namespace are all integral parts of ASP.NET Web API (the pre-.NET Core version), which can't be updated separately nor are they in NuGet - which is why I think you're mixing incompatible assemblies - I hope you're not trying to use ASP.NET-from-.NET Framework 4.x in .NET 5+ project...

Comment: Yes, let me take another look. Also, that Asp.net tag should not be there. let me edit.

Comment: Okay... I was able to get rid of the error by uninstalling the `Fakes` library. I have no idea why that fixed it, but I'll leave this comment for anybody who has this issue in the future.